# What is the difference between $host.UI.RawUI.MaxPhysicalWindowSize Vs $host.UI.RawUI.MaxWindowSize

Tags: powershell

I am trying to maximize the PowerShell console window to fit the screen on which it is running. Have found many article which suggest to use $host.UI.RawUI.MaxWindowSize.

When I try to get $host.UI.RawUI.MaxWindowSize.Width, it's value changes as I resize the console window. On further troubleshooting I came to see $host.UI.RawUI.MaxPhysicalWindowSize. Whose 'Width' value remain same irrespective of console window size.

So, my question is what is the difference between $host.UI.RawUI.MaxWindowSize Vs $host.UI.RawUI.MaxPhysicalWindowSize

Comment: I guess it differs when you have a extended display (a second monitor that extends the desktop to the right, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PSHostRawUserInterface.MaxWindowSize` Gets the size of the largest window possible for the current buffer, current font, and current display hardware. The view window cannot be larger than the screen buffer or the current display (the display the window is rendered on).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostrawuserinterface.maxwindowsize?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0

`PSHostRawUserInterface.MaxPhysicalWindowSize` Gets the largest window possible for the current font and display hardware, ignoring the current buffer dimensions. In other words, the dimensions of the largest window that could be rendered in the current display, if the buffer was at least as large.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostrawuserinterface.maxphysicalwindowsize?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

`$host.UI.RawUI.MaxPhysicalWindowSize` is a maximum window size that could fit a current display (without borders/title).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostrawuserinterface.maxphysicalwindowsize?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0

> Gets the largest window possible for the current font and display
>   hardware, ignoring the current buffer dimensions. In other words, the
>   dimensions of the largest window that could be rendered in the current
>   display, if the buffer was at least as large.